# Load all firebase data into mapView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

I want to make a Map App, where my places ("Events") are stored in a Firebase Database. The Firebase looks like this (example):

[image: database architecture]

I can show ONE SPECIFIC Event from the database like this:

```
func plotEvents(){
    // Show event on map
    mapView.delegate = self
    database.child("event").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else{
            return
        }
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (value["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees), longitude: value["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
        let event2 = Event(title: value["title"] as? String, locationName: value["location"] as? String, discipline: value["discipline"] as? String, coordinate: coordinates)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(event2)
    })
}
```

Now I try to modify my function to show ALL EVENTS from the database. Can someone help me with this? :)

Thank you!

Comment: database.child("event").observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
}

Comment: @El_Tomato Thank you, but it still only loads the ONE event named "event". The other events (e.g. event2408308 or event6299368) aren't showing up...

Comment: That's because you are specifying the child.  Remove child("event"), then.

Comment: hang on. How do I manage the lines from "let coordinates = ..." until "self.mapView.addAnnotation(event2)"

Comment: First, please don't put screen shots of your structures in the question - add them as text so we can copy/paste to use in answers. You need to go up one level to read all events - in other words your events are stored within some parent node `Events/event` and then `Events/event1234` etc. Add the `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value` to that parent `Events` node (which will read in ALL of the child nodes) and then iterate over each one to get to the specific child data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all your events from your Events collection and then loop trough all events and add them.

```
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   db.collection("Events").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let documents = snapshot?.documents {
               for document in documents {
                    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (value["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees), longitude: value["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                    let event = Event(title: value["title"] as? String, locationName: value["location"] as? String, discipline: value["discipline"] as? String, coordinate: coordinates)
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(event)
               }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer by they are using the Realtime Database so this won't work as is. Also, probably need to capture the eventID (documentId aka node key) in the Event class in case they want to modify the event.